# Java's TreeMap replacement in Objective-C?

Tags: java, ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm using `TreeMap` in java code which is going to be ported to ios (objective-c). It should be as efficient as java's original one (for getting **`.subMap()`s** at least). Is there any existing class in Objective-C/Foundation for this? Any existing 3rd-party library if absent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i was able to do it using [`M13MutableOrderedDictionary`](https://github.com/Marxon13/M13OrderedDictionary) for storing sorted dictionary and additional [`NSMutableIndexSet`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableIndexSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for storing sorted keys (you should synchronize changed between both dictionary and index set). For getting `subMap(from, to)` one should find closest existing value using NSMutableIndexSet methods:

- `indexGreaterThanOrEqualToIndex`
- `indexLessThanIndex`
- ...

They help you to find existing keys according to from/to limitations and get `subMap` using M13MutableOrderedDictionary's method `subOrderedDictionaryWithRange`.

Overhead for storing additional keys index, but it works anyway. No better way to do it in Objective-C found, any improvements appreciated. Thanks to *DarkDust*.

Answer (score 1):

Try this old [cocoa-sorted-dictionary](https://code.google.com/p/cocoa-sorted-dictionary/) library.

```
SortedDictionary *dict = [MutableSortedDictionary dictionary];

[dict setValue: @"red"    forKey: @"apple"];
[dict setValue: @"yellow" forKey: @"banana"];
[dict setValue: @"orange" forKey: @"orange"];

NSString *color = [dict objectForKey: @"apple"];
```

You can check if this one realy what you want by reading this [documentation](http://cocoa-sorted-dictionary.s3.amazonaws.com/doc/index.html)

Comment: i can't see any `subMap(from, to)` methods unfortunately. I can use additional sorted array/set for storing sorted keys and skip using any 3-rd party sorted dictionaries, but i need `sub(from,to)` and `first`, `last` methods anyway.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

Look at [M13OrderedDictionary](https://github.com/Marxon13/M13OrderedDictionary). This allows you to generate a new ordered dictionaries using `subOrderedDictionaryWithRange:` which is roughly equivalent to `subMap` (you have to determine the range yourself, though).

You could do it like this:

```
// NSArray *allKeys = [orderedDict allKeys];
// NSUIndex from = [allKeys indexOfObject:fromObject];
// NSUIndex to = [allKeys indexOfObject:toObject];

NSUInteger from = [orderedDict indexOfKey:fromObject];
NSUInteger to  = [orderedDict indexOfKey:fromObject];

if (from != NSNotFound && to != NSNotFound) {
    M13OrderedDictionary *newDict = [orderedDict subOrderedDictionaryWithRange:NSMakeRange(from, to-from)];
}
```

**Old answer:**

Java's `TreeMap` is a sorted map (Java parlance) or dictionary (Objective-C parlance). There is no native Objective-C equivalent and I don't know of any 3rd party implementation that has something like `subMap`.

So you'll need to rebuild this functionality for yourself. A few guides:

- There is a nice article on [subclassing `NSDictionary` to create an ordered dictionary](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/12/ordereddictionary-subclassing-cocoa.html). It's pretty old (pre-ARC days) but the API and concepts have not changed since then (except for ARC, of course).
- You can query the keys of a dictionary with `[myDict allKeys]`, which you can then sort and get your range of keys from. You can then create a new mutable dictionary and copy the relevant key/values.
- Or, you create the inverse of the key range (that is, you create an array of the keys you do *not* want to keep), then do a `[myDict mutableCopy]` and remove all the unwanted keys using [`-[NSMutableDictionary removeObjectsForKeys:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableDictionary/removeObjectsForKeys:).

BTW, note that unlike Java, Objective-C does not let you pick an implementation, it is automatically chosen at runtime for you. That's why there are only two classes to chose from: the immutable `NSDictionary` and the mutable `NSMutableDictionary`.

Comment: thanks for the links. but it seems that i'm suggested to reinvent the wheel .. no existing implementations in obj-c really?

Comment: Well, there _are_ ordered dictionary implementations, for example [this one](https://github.com/Marxon13/M13OrderedDictionary) or [this one](https://github.com/rhodgkins/RDHOrderedDictionary). There surely are even more. But I haven't seen one with `subMap` functionality.

Comment: @4ntoine: See my updated answer, I think I found a solution for you.

Comment: i have to iterate the keys to find range and it's dramatically inefficient. the dictionary should provide methods to get `first`, `last`, `subMap(from)`, `subMap(to)`, `submap(from, to)` and use binary search or balanced trees (as far as i understand) behind the scene to find the range

Comment: i think i should take a look at that method to get the range efficiently

Comment: See my yet-again-updated answer on how to get the range. If you want to use a binary search, [you don't need to implement it yourself, NSArray already provides it](http://oleb.net/blog/2013/07/nsarray-binary-search/).

Comment: Or: let M13OrderedDictionary do the search for you with `indexOfKey:`.

Comment: `indexOfKey` is not enough to get `subMap(from)` is `from` is absent in the array. f.e. i want to get keys more than 3 and keys are 1,5,6. indexof:3 is not found and i can't get 5,6

Comment: Then I suggest you look into `NSArray`'s `indexOfObjectPassingTest:` and `indexOfObjectWithOptions:passingTest:`. If you're only dealing with numbers as keys, are not inserting/deleting keys and you need to do the lookup often _and measured that you actually have a performance problem_ you might want to turn your keys into a [NSIndexSet](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSIndexSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for fast lookup.

Comment: I actually think you're trapped in pre-mature optimization thinking: you seem to worry about performance problems without actually having seen any. I do multi-media processing (DVB/MPEG-2) on iOS devices since iPhone 3GS, iOS devices actually have a lot of performance unless you screw up your design badly… but it's not my app, use and do whatever you like :-) I'm not forcing you to use this particular implementation.

Comment: unfortunately i have to think about performance first of all and i've noted that in the question first of all. otherwise i would not use TreeMap but iterate array all the time.

Comment: Yeah, we iOS kiddies sure know nothing about writing high-performance, low-latency applications like multi-media, games and similar stuff. Good luck.

Comment: the only "high-performance" you have is provided by absence of VM and if obj-c even have no sortable dictionaries means nobody cares about performance

Comment: it's slow because developers don't think about underlying algo behind the scene not because of language impl peformance. agree with you, no more trolling and sorry for that. it's about embedded compiler for iOS - searching open/close symbols like {} and (). and yes - it's already working on android

Comment: You always talk about "slow", but have you _measured_? We don't care about the algorithm since the system picks an appropriate one at runtime and even switches it when necessary. You really, _really_ need to [read this blog post](http://ridiculousfish.com/blog/posts/array.html) (it's about arrays, but the same is true of NSDictionary)!

Comment: Since you don't seem to have any other options at the moment, I suggest you benchmark `M13OrderedDictionary` and see for yourself whether it's useful or not. It's backed by NSDictionary (for key lookup) and NSArray (for index lookup).